# pypy3 dyld can not be found in homebrew

Tags: homebrew, pypy

I got the following error when I use homebrew. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pypy/7.1.1_1/libexec/lib/libpypy-c.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Here is the output of `brew doctor`.

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Some installed formulae were deleted!
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  inchi
  python@2
  libmpc@0.8
  pygtk
  isl@0.11
  f2c
  indigo
  mpfr@2
  gmp@4
  phantomjs
  phantomjs
  rdkit
  casperjs
  mumps
  ecj
  pygobject
  isl@0.12
  gcc@4.8
  gcc@4.8
Warning: Calling a Formula#patches definition is deprecated! Use 'patch do' block calls instead.
Please report this issue to the docmunch/pdftk tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/docmunch/homebrew-pdftk/pdftk.rb:15


Warning: You have the following deprecated, official taps tapped:
  Homebrew/homebrew-dupes
  Homebrew/homebrew-fuse
  Homebrew/homebrew-head-only
  Homebrew/homebrew-versions
  Homebrew/homebrew-x11
Untap them with `brew untap`.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config

Warning: Putting non-prefixed coreutils in your path can cause gmp builds to fail.

Warning: Putting non-prefixed findutils in your path can cause python builds to fail.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.10.4.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.2.0.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libpostal.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.0.12.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.0.12.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.0.12.4.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/libpostal/libpostal.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
...  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/wkhtmltox/image.h
  /usr/local/include/wkhtmltox/pdf.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.la
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.la
  /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.la
  /usr/local/lib/libpostal.la
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.la
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpostal.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pocketsphinx.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sphinxbase.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
  /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.a
  /usr/local/lib/libpostal.a
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.a
  /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  inchi
  mpich
  ssed
  python
  libmpc@0.8
  nss
  isl@0.11
  numpy
  mpfr@2
  gmp@4
  poppler
  nspr
  scipy
  gcc@4.8

Warning: Some installed formulae are not readable:
  indigo: Unsupported special dependency :python

  rdkit: Unsupported special dependency :python3

Warning: Your Xcode (10.3) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 11.3.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.


Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
  /usr/local/share/man/man5/package-lock.json.5
  /usr/local/share/man/man7/removing-npm.7

Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install imlib2 libcaca opusfile

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [issue 3229](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/issues/3229) on the PyPy issue tracker. It seems our buildbot is using a `brew install`ed version of libffi. Until we solve this, you should be able to do `brew install pypy3`. Help from someone who can make the PyPy build look more like the CPython one (which apparently does not have this problem) are welcome.